# How can I create this following style with CSS3?

Tags: html, css, layout, styles

I would like to get this style in CSS3:

[CSS3 layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJRBX.png)

For now, I have the simplest thing, the middle square with the following code:

HTML (pretty irrelevant, but I guess the tag does not need to be a div tag):

```
<div id="divBorder">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#divBorder{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 15;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -110px 0 0 -160px;
}
```

So, I just have basically centered the middle square in the center of the screen and that's all, I can't find a way to do the other two half squares on both sides of the full one.

I hope you can help me, thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired layout with the following markup, using [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: mediumspringgreen;
}

div {
  flex: 4;
  display: flex;
  background-color: darkviolet;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
}

section:nth-child(even) {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: darkorchid;
}

footer {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: deeppink;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header></header>
  <div>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.inner {
border:solid; 


}

.outer {display: flex;
flex-direction:row;}

.side {width: 25%; height: 50px;}

.center {width: 50%; height: 50px}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="side inner"></div>
<div class="center inner"></div>
<div class="side inner"></div>
</div>
```

You can use flexbox to do this. You can either set the width in procentage or you can look into sizing it with flexbox.